# Understanding proof of the Eisenbud, Commutative Algebra, Theorem 13.9 - Going down for integral extensions of normal rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am reading the Eisenbud's commutative Algebra book, proof of Theorem 13.9 and stuck at some statement.

Let me first raise a question that I think is relevant.

**Q.** Let $R$ be a normal domain  with finite extension of fields $K' \subseteq K'' \subseteq K(R) $ ( $K(R)$ is the quotient field ), possibly simple extension. Consider $R':=K'\cap R$ and $R'':=K''\cap R$.

Then, 1) $R' \hookrightarrow R''$ is an integral extension?
2) The field extension $K(R'')/ K(R')$ is finite?

I want to understand proof of next theorem in the Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra book.

> Theorem 13.9 (Going Down for integral extensions of normal rings). Let $S$ be a normal domain, and let $R$ be a domain containing $S$. If $R$ is integral over $S$, then **going down** holds between $R$ and $S$ : Given primes $Q_1 \supset Q$ and a prime $P_1$ of $R$ lying over $Q_1$, there exists a prime $P$ of $R$ lying over $Q$ and contained in $P_1$ ( Figure 13.1 ).  This results holds even if $S$ and $R$ are not Noetherian.

[image]

**For the proof, he first proved the theorem for case that $K(R)$ is a finite extension of $K(S)$.**

And completion of the proof of the theorem 13.9 is as folllows :

[image]

Here, Figure 13.3 is,

[image]

I want to understand the underlined statement. Return to the FIgure 13.1. above. Let's make substitution :

$$ S \to R':=K'\cap R \\ R \to R'':=K''\cap R \\ Q_1 \to P_1':= P_1 \cap R' \\ P_1 \to P_1'':=P_1 \cap R'' \\ Q \to P' \\ \exists P \to \exists P'' $$

[image]

Then, if our question is true, then as Eisenbud argues ( by the theorem 13.9 for the case that $K(R)/K(S)$ is finite ), there exists $P'' \subseteq R''$ contained in $P_1'':=P_1 \cap R''$ and contracting to $Q$ in $S$ ( $\because$ $S\cap P''= ( S\cap R') \cap P'' = S \cap ( R' \cap P'') \stackrel{\text{!}}{=} S \cap  P' = Q$ ).

And my origial question is really true? Can anyone help?

Comment: If you are not fixated to understand Eisenbud's proof, then the proofs on Atiyah& Macdonald's book or on Zariski& Samuel's book are also very good. I also humbly recommend my passage https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/689936366 on the proof of the theorem, which is based on Zariski& Samuel's and fulfilled some detail.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation. I checked the proof of the Atiyah - Macdonald's book ( Theorem 5.16 ). And I'm a little bit puzzled at one step of the proof. In the proof, in the second paragraph, he wrote that "...so that the minimal equation for $s$ over $K$ is obtained by dividing $(1)$ by $x^r$, and is therefore, say, $s^r + v_1 s^{r-1} + \cdots + v_r = 0$, where $v_i = u_i/x^i$." I don't know why this is the minimal equation for $s$ over $K$ (  so that we may apply (5.15) in his book to deduce that each $v_i$ is in $A$  ; c.f. third paragraph of his proof. )~

Comment: And apart from that, I still curious whether my original questions in this post are true. Anyway thank you for link.

Comment: As for your question on Atiyah-Macodonald's proof: (In what follows $x$ is the element in the proof, and $X$ is the intermediate for polynomials.)
Let $R$ be a domain and $K={\rm Frac}(R)$.
If $S$ is a ring containing $R$ and $s\in S$, then
$$\{f\in K[X]: f(s)=0\}$$ is an ideal in $K[X]$. Since $K[X]$ is a PID, therefore the above ideal is generated by a monic polynomial $g\in K[X]$. $g$ is said to be the *minimal polynomial* of $s$ over $R$. (not finished)

Comment: Since $s=\frac yx$, the two ideals of $K[X]$, $$I_1=\{\phi(X)\in K[X]:\phi(s)=0 \}$$ and $$I_2=\{\psi(x\cdot X)\in K[X]:\psi(y)=0 \}$$ are equal.
Since $\{\psi(X)\in K[X]:\psi(y)=0\}$ is generated by $$X^r+u_1X^{r-1}+\cdots+u_r,$$
therefore $I_2$ is generated by $$ x^rX^r+u_1x^{r-1}X^{r-1}+\cdots+u_r, $$
or by $$X^r+\frac{u_1}{x}X^{r-1}+\cdots+\frac{u_r}{x^r} $$ (dividing $x^r$). Since $I_1=I_2$ this polynomial generates $I_2$, and is therefore $s$'s minimal polynomial, by construction of $I_1$.

Comment: I regret to say I can neither catch Eisenbud's proof. You can start a bounty for the question if you want to receive an answer for the explanation of Eisenbud's proof.

Comment: O.K. Thank you for kind explanation  ! ~